# Telegram bot can not send inline query to a chat

Tags: telegram-bot

I created an inline bot, that works great: if I type `@BOT_NAME 1234`, it posts an inline result from the bot.

Now I wish that bot could post that result by itself.

But when I call `sendMessage @BOT_NAME 1234`, the message from the bot is just the text *@BOT_NAME 1234*. If I retype the same text as a telegram user, the inline is working again.

Please see my image to this:

[image: Please, see to the image]

What parameter do I miss, or is it couldn't be done at all?